# Cookie not set when I host Java website

Tags: java

I am using a Java 8 and I am trying to set some values using cookies. It works successfully on localhost.

But, when I host this site on web server then the cookies are not set successfully. That's why I am unable to retrives values from cookies.
     What I can do for solve this problem?

```
public void setCookie(String mob_num ,String operator1,String pay_code,String pay_circle_code,String amount,HttpServletResponse response)
{
    System.out.println("inside cookie function");
    Cookie  cookie = new Cookie("mobnum", mob_num);
    response.addCookie(cookie);`enter code here`
    cookie=new Cookie("paycode", pay_code);
    response.addCookie(cookie);
    cookie=new Cookie("amount",amount);`enter code here`
    response.addCookie(cookie);
    cookie=new Cookie("name",pay_circle_code);
    response.addCookie(cookie);
    System.out.println("inside cookie :mob = "+mob_num+"\noperator =  "+operator1+"\npay_circle_code =   "+pay_circle_code+"\namount +  "+amount+"\npay code =   "+pay_code);        
}
```

enter code here

Comment: Share the code if you can

Comment: Is the `Set-Cookie`-header sent back to the client? Does the client accept cookies from the web-server's URL?

Comment: can You explain it in above example What to do .